# Error Building Scaffolding Site Yesod

Tags: mysql, haskell, yesod

I have tried to setup the Yesod scaffolding site with MySQL, in the book it said to use `yesod init` but apparently that command no longer exists and I should use `stack new project_name template`. So I ran `stack new project_name yesod-mysql` which created all the files but then when running `yesod devel` from within the directory my site is in I get two errors. Below are the log contents for each:

mysql-0.1.4.log:

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Temp\stack23220\mysql-0.1.4\Setup.hs, C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Temp\stack23220\mysql-0.1.4\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\Main.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( C:\sr\setup-exe-src\setup-shim-Z6RU0evB.hs, C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Temp\stack23220\mysql-0.1.4\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\StackSetupShim.o )
Linking C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Temp\stack23220\mysql-0.1.4\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\setup\setup.exe ...
Configuring mysql-0.1.4...
setup.exe: The program 'mysql_config' is required but it could not be found
```

pcre-light-0.4.0.4.log:

```
Configuring pcre-light-0.4.0.4...
Cabal-simple_Z6RU0evB_1.24.2.0_ghc-8.0.2.exe: The program 'pkg-config' version
>=0.9.0 is required but it could not be found.
```

I've searched around a bit for a solution but couldn't find much. I also tried following the quick start guide on the Yesod website but that didn't fix anything.

I'm running Windows 7.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: I installed pkg-config via MSYS2 but that didn't help. I also tried installing MySQL but that didn't help regarding the `mysql-config` problem.

Comment: Do you have `mysql_config` and `pkg-config` installed? The former I've never heard of, but the latter is quite well-known, and I'm assuming the former serves a similar purpose to the latter, but in a mySQL-specific context. (Note: if you don't have the program installed, I find it hard to see how searching on the internet did not yield the basic steps needed to install it. Perhaps you should also include what fixes you've tried...)

Comment: @user2407038 sorry I should have made it clear in the question, I will edit it after posting this comment. I installed pkg-config via msys2 but still get the issue with Yesod. I presume something needs to be added to the path but I can't find any reference of that on the internet. I can't find anything about mysql-config. I tried to install MySQL but again that didn't help.

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/paul-rouse/mysql/issues/3. I recommend you bump that github issue so that they are aware that this is still a problem.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql error seems like this can help

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```